# why solve() throws this result Empty sym: 0-by-1 and fails to get the correct results

Tags: matlab

Take a look at this script

```
syms v1 v2 v3
eqns = [5*v1 -2*v2  -3*v3 == 24, ...
        4*v1 +5*v2        ==  0, ...
       -6*v1 +12*v2 +8*v3 ==  0];
vars = [v1 v2 v3];
answer = solve(eqns,vars);
vpa(answer.v1)
vpa(answer.v2)
vpa(answer.v3)
```

which yields this results:

```
ans =
Empty sym: 0-by-1
ans =
Empty sym: 0-by-1
ans =
Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

But with the following script:

```
syms v1 v2 v3
eqn1 = 5*v1  -2*v2 -3*v3  == 24;
eqn2 = 4*v1  +5*v2        ==  0;
eqn3 = -6*v1 +12*v2 +8*v3 ==  0;
eqns = [eqn1,eqn2,eqn3];
vars = [v1 v2 v3];
answer = solve(eqns, vars);
vpa(answer.v1)
vpa(answer.v2)
vpa(answer.v3)
```

The correct result is yielded as:

```
ans =
32.0
ans =
-25.6
ans =
62.4
```

What is the settle difference that leads to this inconsistency? My Matlab version is 2019.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from line

```
eqns = [5*v1 -2*v2  -3*v3 == 24, ...
        4*v1 +5*v2        ==  0, ...
       -6*v1 +12*v2 +8*v3 ==  0];
```

If you execute this line and then enter eqns in console you will get:

```
>> eqns
eqns =
[ 5*v1, -2*v2, -3*v3 == 24, 4*v1, 5*v2 == 0, -6*v1, 12*v2, 8*v3 == 0]
```

That is to say 8 equations instead of 3. That's why no solution is found. The problem disappears if you add some spaces. Strange behavior, it looks like the sequence space->plus/minus sign->digit is understood as a new equation. Hence,

```
syms v1 v2 v3
eqns = [5*v1 - 2*v2  - 3*v3 == 24,...
        4*v1 + 5*v2         == 0,...
       -6*v1 + 12*v2 + 8*v3 == 0];
vars = [v1 v2 v3];
answer = solve(eqns);
vpa(answer.v1)
vpa(answer.v2)
vpa(answer.v3)
```

will return the correct answer:

```
ans =
32.0
ans =
-25.6
ans =
62.4
```